# Apply css class from another page to title with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have a text input with a toggle button. I want to apply/remove a CSS `style:word-wrap: break-word;` to the `title` from `page 2`. How should I proceed?

**Page 1 :**

```
  <h2>Title</h2>

  <input ng-model="card.title">

  <md-button ng-model="card.title" ng-click="toggleWrap()">
     <md-icon>{{(wrapText===true) ? 'wrap_text' : 'remove'}}</md-icon>
  </md-button>
```

**JS 1 :**

```
  $scope.wrapText = true;
  $scope.toggleWrap = function() {
     $scope.wrapText = !$scope.wrapText;
  };
```

**Page 2 :**

```
<h2 ng-class="{'word-wrap': yesORno}">{{title}}</h2>
```

Comment: What's `yesORno`?  Don't you mean `wrapText`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple. Just bind the variable in `$rootScope` like this and it will be accessible in all your controllers/html:

```
$rootScope.wrapText = true;
$scope.toggleWrap = function() {
  $rootScope.wrapText = $rootScope.wrapText ? false : true;
};
```

Then you can set in your html:

```
<h2 ng-class="{'word-wrap': wrapText}">{{title}}</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

If $scope.wrapText is your toggle value then,

```
<h2 ng-class="{'word-wrap': wrapText}">{{title}}</h2>
```

If page 1 and page 2 have different controller then either you can keep wrapText as global variable such as $rootScope or use service communicate to between the controllers .